# No exception is thrown when socket is closed

Tags: java, sockets

When the server socket is closed the client doesn't receive any exception even after **writing** on the **OutputStream** and the server socket is already **close**.

Giving the following classes to test that:

```
public class ModemServerSocket {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(63333);
        Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        String s;

        while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
            if (s.equals("q")) {                
                break;
            }
        }

        serverSocket.close();
    }

}
```

public class ModemClientSocket {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 63333);
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"), true);
        String[] sArray = {"hello", "q", "still there?"};
        for (String s : sArray) {
            writer.println(s);
            if (s.equals("q")) {
                Thread.sleep(5 * 1000);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Whoop. No exception. The client didn't notice.");       
    }

}
```

What I did was to launch the ModemServerSocket application then after that I launched the ModemClientSocket application.

**ModemServerSocket Output**:

```
hello 
q
```

**ModemClientSocket Output**:

```
Whoop. No exception. The client didn't notice.
```

Is this the expected behavior? Why is happening this?

However I did another test where I close the ModemClientSocket and the ModemServerSocket tries to read from the InputStream in that case I got an **java.net.SocketException** which is what I expected. The weird thing is that is not happening for the **PrintWriter** (OutputStream) and no exception is thrown.

I used **Java 1.6.0 Update 26** for the tests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting the JDK documentation of PrintWriter below.

> Methods in this class **never throw I/O exceptions**, although some of its constructors may. The client may inquire as to whether any errors have occurred by invoking checkError().

[PrinterWriter Documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html)

Answer (score 3):

I believe that closing the ServerSocket just means that no *new* connections will be accepted -- it doesn't close connections that have already been set up (You'd need to call client.close() in ModemServerSocket to do that).

Answer (score 3):

Based on some tests I ran, even if you don't use PrintWriter, and instead write directly to socket.getOutputStream(), I don't think you're guaranteed an exception when the server closes its socket, but if you call write() enough times it seems that eventually you will get an exception.

Note that there is sometimes a difference in behavior depending on whether the client and server are on the same machine or not.  When running locally, fewer writes seem to be needed before the "SocketException: Broken pipe" exception happens.

If you want to *realiably* detect that the socket is closed you need to *read* from it, and check whether the read returns -1.  (and, of course, handle any exceptions)

For example:

```
if (socket.getInputStream().read(bytearray) < 0)
    break;
```

If the server isn't sending anything you can hack things up by calling socket.setSoTimeout(1), and handling/ignoring the SocketTimeoutException, but the "right" way to do it is probably to start with [SocketChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html) instead of Socket so you can use a [Selector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html)  which should notify you when the read() method can be called.

btw, the serverSocket.close() line is a bit misleading, and should probably be client.close(). However, the class exits immediately after that, so all sockets will be closed anyway.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that read() is more reliable than write() with respect to catching connection errors.

Comment: I thought out.flush would throught an exception but it didn't instead it kept writing to socket as if it is alive. Then i used read() which blocked the thread if other socket died. Then i used read + setsotimeout which worked perfectly. Thanks